# Language hint parser failed for C++

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editor

Currently on SO using:

```
<!-- language: c++ -->
```

Makes subsequent editing of a post fail, none of the editor buttons are visible and the keyboard shortcuts do nothing. Firefox gives an error in the console:

```
Syntax error wmd.en.js:2
```

and Chrome fails identically. Using the following hint instead works as expected:

```
<!-- language: lang-cpp -->
```

This was observed with the initial revision of my answer to: [How to use weak_ptr in swig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803149/how-to-use-weak-ptr-in-swig/24898632#24898632) and can still be reproduced by attempting [editing revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24898632/edit/44194637-3f14-49b6-be29-637ab50b789f).

Comment: Chrome gives console error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^c++/: Nothing to repeat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I replaced the use of a regular expression there with a "startswith" function that does the same.

Given that it was an invalid regular expression causing the issue, that's now sorted!